# Pip can't install tensorflow cause it doesn't exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to install tensorflow 2 in windows by using `pip`,but it outputs the following error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)`

Ah! I did `pip list` and tensorflow  don't appears

Comment: Which version of the Python interpreter do you want to install it for? Make sure tensorflow is supported on this version of Python! In case it's Python 3.8 then it is not supported yet as of today.

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks! I'm using python 3.8! What version I have to use to can install tensorflow?

Comment: You need to use 3.5-3.7 at this point. You can look on PyPI for the available wheels: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current latest tensorflow release ([2.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0/#files)) on Windows, you need Python 3.5, 3.6, or [3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370a1/). It is **not** supported for other versions, such as Python 3.8 for example, 2.7 is supported but not on Windows.

Install python3.7 on Unix systems with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Install python3.7 on Unix systems with access to the AUR:

```
yay -S python37
```

Then you can install tensorflow with:

```
python3.7 -m pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: That is just not true. Tensorflow is compatible with more versions of the Python interpreter than just 3.6. How did you come up with this? The current latest version (2.1.0) is compatible with 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7.

Comment: @sinoroc You're correct, 3.7 is the latest version, my bad

Answer (score 1):

[Here, under *system requirements*](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#system-requirements), it details that the latest current *tensorflow* release (2.1.0) is compatible with versions 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7 of the Python interpreter on Windows (and 2.7 on other platforms).

- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
- https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0/#files